# Binding with the same name in different windows xaml MVVM

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

I think is possible, but is it to be good practice to have Data Binding with the same name in different windows? Or every binding is need to be with unique name in all application, not only in the scope of window. In case we used MVVM.

```
<DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding StartMeasureDateRestoreSelect}" />
```

This code in the Window1.xaml and in the Window2.xaml is problem to be with the same name like here is "StartMeasureDateRestoreSelect" or good practice is to be with the different name.

Sorry for my bad English and not very good explaining.

Answer (score 0):

It is important to have various names as it gives cleaner and nicer look for other developers who will see you program.

Read about [Naming Convention](http://Naming%20convention).

**As Wiki says:**

> In computer programming, a [naming convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention) is a set of rules for
>   choosing the character sequence to be used for identifiers which
>   denote variables, types, functions, and other entities in source code
>   and documentation.
>
> Reasons for using a naming convention (as opposed to allowing
>   programmers to choose any character sequence) include the following:
>
> - to reduce the effort needed to read and understand source code;[1](http://Naming%20convention)
> - to enable code reviews to focus on more important issues than arguing over syntax and naming standards.
> - to enable code quality review tools to focus their reporting mainly on significant issues other than syntax and style preferences.
> - to enhance source code appearance (for example, by disallowing overly long names or unclear abbreviations).

Syntax for naming properties in C#:

```
private DataTable employeeDataTable;
public DataTable EmployeeDataTable
{
   get { return employeeDataTable; }
   set
       {
         employeeDataTable = value;       
       }
}
```

It is better to name `bool` properties with prefix **Is**

```
public bool IsBusy { get; set; }
```

And name your class/properties/variables to understand what goal of them. For example:

```
public class Person//goal of this class is keep state/info about Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }//goal of this property is keep state/info about 
   //Name of Person

    private void PopulateByPeople()// in my view it self-explainable name of method
    {
        employeeDataTable = new DataTable();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            employeeDataTable.Columns.Add(i.ToString() + " column");
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)//Adding 50 DataRows
        {
            var theRow = employeeDataTable.NewRow();
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            {
                theRow[j] = "o " + (i).ToString();
            }
            employeeDataTable.Rows.Add(theRow);                
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: OK. For cleaner is good, and I try to use this rule, but if I have two DatePickers in different windows which is have same functionality for DisplayDateStart and DispkayDateEnd, then is not so easy to think different cleaner name.

Comment: @evelikov92 feel free to ask any question. If you want to clarify answer, you should ask questions:)